# Making an environment to draw over a picture with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, xparse, tikz-pic

Following up on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/161388), I've decided to just make this a new environment. Below is my MWE using packages `xparse` and `tikz`:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{overdraw}{ o o m +b } {
    { % begin "\begin{overdraw}"
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep = 0] (image) at (0,0) {
            \includegraphics{#3}
        }; % add image at coordinate (0, 0)
        \IfNoValueTF{#2} {
            \IfNoValueTF{#1} {
                \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                % If Optional Arg #1 is empty
            } { \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)/#1},y={(image.north west)}] }
                % #1 not empty
        } % If Optional Arg #2 is empty
            { \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)/#1},y={(image.north west)/#2}] }
            % #2 not empty
    } % end "\begin{overdraw}"
    { % begin "\end{overdraw}"
        \end{scope} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } % end "\end{overdraw}"
}

\begin{document}
\begin{overdraw}{sample.jpg}
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
\end{overdraw}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this returns an error message that goes:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.16 \newpage
              [1]

! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20 \end
         {overdraw}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.20 \end
         {overdraw}
End of file on the terminal!
```

What does `\newpage` have to do with anything I wrote? Is there any way to fix this problem?

EDIT: The package repository in full can be found [HERE at Github](https://www.github.com/thekpaul/OverDraw). Passers-by are welcome to leave comments and notes on tips for managing and developing a good package `:D`

Comment: I doesn't solve the problem, but `\includegraphics{#3};}` should be `\includegraphics{#3}};`.

Comment: @Ignasi it definitely should, what an embarrassing typo. And indeed, it wasn't a solution to the major problem here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Overview

You have a brace matching problem, and the divisions on the `x` and `y` vectors were written in a way that isn't supported by TikZ. The following works for me. I have removed your `+b` argument specifier, since you don't use this argument at all.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{overdraw}{ o o m }%
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[anchor=south west, inner sep = 0] (image) at (0,0) {
        \includegraphics{#3}
      }; % add image at coordinate (0, 0)

      \IfNoValueTF{#2} {% optional argument #2 not provided
        \IfNoValueTF{#1} {% optional argument #1 not provided
          \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        }{% #1 provided
          \pgfmathparse{1/(#1)}
          \begin{scope}[x={($\pgfmathresult*(image.south east)$)},
                        y={(image.north west)}]
        }
      }{% #2 provided
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myXfactor}{1/(#1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myYfactor}{1/(#2)}

        \begin{scope}[x={($\myXfactor*(image.south east)$)},
                      y={($\myYfactor*(image.north west)$)}]
      }
  }{
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }% end "\end{overdraw}"

\begin{document}
\begin{overdraw}[1.5][0.8]{example-image}
  \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
\end{overdraw}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Code formatting and extraneous spaces

I reformatted the code to make it a bit easier to read (IMHO). Beware of introducing extraneous spaces, since you are *not* using `\ExplSyntaxOn` here (note the place of the `%` characters at environment start, before `\begin{tikzpicture}`, and at environment end, after `\end{tikzpicture}`). To see my point, try the above code with:

```latex
\begin{document}
a\begin{overdraw}{example-image}
  \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
\end{overdraw}b
\end{document}
```

You'll get this:

[image: ab OK]

See the `a` and `b` lying on the image baseline? Now, remove the two percent characters I mentioned (before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and after `\end{tikzpicture}`) and you'll obtain this:

[image: ab BAD]

The whole takes two lines because one `\linewidth` isn't large enough to hold the indentation box, the `a`, the `b`, two interword spaces and the image (given the default value of `\parindent`).

## Dividing a vector by a scalar in TikZ

I added `\pgfmathparse` computations and the `calc` TikZ library in order to do the divisions on the `x` and `y` vectors that you apparently desired.

## On the “non-empty” vs. “provided“ argument check

Please note that:

- `xparse`'s `\IfNoValueTF` test does *not* test if the optional argument is empty, it tests whether it has been *provided*. One can provide an empty argument, it is still provided. If the criterion you want to decide against is emptiness, I suggest using `O{}` in the argument specification of `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and then checking with, for instance, `etoolbox`'s `\ifblank` command (i.e., 1) you declare the argument as an optional one whose default value is empty, and 2) you check whether it is empty).
- Using `\IfValueTF` instead of `\IfNoValueTF` is likely to make the logic easier to follow, especially when there are imbricated tests like here.

Comment: Not sure why, but there was no overprint until I deleted `+m` in the argument specification.

Comment: I expanded the answer, please reread. What do you mean by an overprint?..

Comment: Ah, right, `+m` is a mandatory argument and we don't provide it! Either provide one or remove the arg specifier.

Comment: Just TeXed your altered file. No change. With the `{ o o m +m}` argument specification, there is no red rectangle *overprint*. Removing the `+m` fixes the problem. I'm using MacTeX 2019, recently updated.

Comment: Look in the last edit: I provided an empty arg when the environment is used. Otherwise, remove the `+m` since you don't use it. I let it in place because I thought it is part of your future plans for the environment. PS.: the rectangle **is** drawn with current code.

Comment: Yes, but surely, having coded `\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle node {X} (0.78,0.75);`, you intended the `rectangle` to appear. As such, that rectangle is said to *overprint* the graphic. And it was not my environment.

Comment: That was probably the argument in excess (see my last edit: I have removed the arg since you don't use it at all). It is now overprinted for me. The only thing that doesn't work, AFAIK, is how you divide the coordinates. I have to dig the tikz calc syntax for that, unless someone here knows better. :)

Comment: I have expanded my explanations and fixed your code in order to perform the divisions of the `x` and `y` vectors by scalars that you apparently desired (the scalars in question being the optional arguments of the `overdraw` environment). The way you wrote these divisions isn't supported by TikZ, AFAICT. I've also added several screenshots.

Comment: @sgmoye Sorry, there was a little misunderstanding, my fault. 1) Since you've been the only person to comment on my answer, I thought you were the OP, therefore I have used the word “you” or “your“ many times when referring to the OP's question or code. :-/ 2) For me, the subject of the question was really the compilation error, as can be seen in the [first rev](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/493032/1) of my answer. I only addressed the other problems later. 3) **I** didn't code the `\draw[red,ultra ...`: this was quite at the bottom of the OP's code, I pasted it and overlooked it...

Comment: @sgmoye ... at first (only concerned with the compilation error). That was until you started to mention the overprinting thing. 4) “Draw a rectangle on the image” would have been clearer to me, but I eventually understood what overprinting meant in this context. :-) 5) The absence of the rectangle you noticed was due to the excess `+b`/`+m` argument grabbed by the environment. Adding `+m` with no corresponding argument in the call only grabs the `\draw` token and leaves `[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);` in the input stream, which TikZ then royally ignores;

Comment: @sgmoye ... you can verify this by either suppressing the `\draw` token manually or pasting all the `[red,ultra thick, ... ,0.75);` before `}{ \end{scope}` inside the environment! 6) AFAIK, I have fixed all issues.

Comment: @KPaul If you accept my answer and are interested in having empty optional arguments treated as if they had not been provided at all, I can implement the `\ifblank` test mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I gathered as much, so absolutely no apology necessary. I was also confused by what the purpose of the original code was -- made me hesitant to answer at all. Easy to make the code work (in any number of ways!), but to what end? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @sgmoye I'm not sure either about what the division will be useful for, practically. But probably the OP has an idea. :)

Comment: @frougon Thank you for the answer, and sorry for the delayed reply. The division is one of many trial-and-errors I'm implementing to impose a height-to-width ratio, the goal being the top-rightmost corner of an image being (x, y) with x:y being the ratio of the picture, rather than the somewhat-confusing (1,1). And I never knew the percentages behind each line had other meanings than commenting! The `ifblank` test is also a very good suggestion - I'll make sure to add that to my list of to-dos `:D`

Comment: @K.Paul Thanks for explaining the idea behind the divisions. You may want to look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) regarding the percent signs. If you have difficulty with `\ifblank`, dont hesitate to ask.

Comment: I've simplified the code doing the divisions a tiny bit thanks to `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Comment: +1: very helpful answer